# MS Visual Studio 2010 Pro fails to create a datasource for a gridview

Tags: asp.net, .net

I have multiple TabPanels with one GridView each. I successfully used the GUI to set the datasource for each GridView. After adding the latest TabPanel and GridView I created the datasource and finished, but it didn't create any datasource. The datasource dropdownlist in GridView is empty. There are no errors, it just doesn't do anything when I click "finish". Now I can't create a new datasource for any new GridView on any tab. Existing GridViews and datasources work fine. What could cause this?

Comment: OK, I found the problem. I had a datasource with same id (SqlDataSource1) on another TabPanel. I renamed all datasources and now it seems to be working again.

I don't know why Studio's GUI gives SqlDataSource1 as a default id if it's already in use. It would also be nice if you'd get some error when trying to use id which is taken.

Answer (score -1):

May be u did copy & paste your code, Or any panel, VS give unique name to sqldatasource always.